# c# obtaining property values from object

Tags: c#

I am trying to use a method to create an object and return that object to main(). Once in main I want to be able to access the properties of that object such as print Holly.age. VS does not recognize the object Holly in main() to have any properties. Is anyone able to tell what I am doing wrong or let me know if it's not something possible in c#.

Thanks in advance to anyone who gives there time to help.

```
class program
{ 

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object Holly = createobject(Holly, 21);
        int hollyage = Holly.age; // This Line is the problem Holly.age is not recognized 
        // as anything

    }

    public static object createobject(string name, int i)
    {
    Cat Holly = new Cat(name, i);
    return Holly;
    }

    public class Cat
    {
    public string name;
    public int age;
    public string Name
        {
            get { return this.name; }
            set { this.name = value; }
        }
    public int Age
        {
            get { return this.age; }
            set { this.age = value; }
        }
    public Cat(string name, int age)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }

}
```

Comment: Aside from anything else, now would be a good time to learn about: 1) .NET naming conventions; 2) Indentation conventions; 3) automatically implemented properties.

Answer (score 2):

> VS does not recognize the object Holly in main() to have any properties

This is because you have declared `Holly` to be `object` rather than `Cat`, and similarly your create routine returns `object` rather than `Cat`.

To be able to use any of the properties of `Cat` you need to cast `Holly` back to `Cat` or better still, return `Cat` from your create routine. Unless you intend to extend your create routine to do more, you don't really need it and can simply do:

```
Cat Holly = new Cat("Holly", 21);
```

You also have both public fields and public properties in your `Cat` class. The fields should be made private, but that's not the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your method `createobject` returns an `object`. So you must first cast it back into `Cat` before you can access `Age`:

```
int hollyage = ((Cat)Holly).Age;
```

In addition your call to the `createobject` is wrong. It requests a string. Change to:

```
createobject("Holly", 21);
```

---

The correct way to write your code would be:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //variable name in camelCase.
    //"Holly" is a string

    object holly = CreateObject("Holly", 21);

    //Casting from object to Cat so you can access Age property
    int hollyAge = ((Cat)holly).Age; 
}

//Function names EachWorkCapitalized
public static object CreateObject(string name, int i)
{
    Cat holly = new Cat(name, i);
    return holly;
}

public class Cat
{
    //If you implement your properties with the default get set behavior 
    //better use automatically implemented properties
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public Cat(string name, int age)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need `public static object createobject()`

You can simply remove that and change your Main to:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Cat Holly = new Cat("Holly", 21);
        int hollyage = Holly.age; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Holly is defined as an object class, and object classes do not have an `age` or `Age` property.

You should change the line as:

```
Cat Holly = createObject("Holly", 21) as Cat;
```

Then the intellisense will recognize the Holly variable as being of type `Cat`.

Answer (score 0):

You could always cast the object to the correct type to access it's members.

```
int hollyage = ((Cat)Holly).Age;
```